# Phonebook python

Tags: python

Hi i am new to python an di recently created a phonebook using the dictionary function and then changed into exe using py2exe. I am facing a problem now i enter names in to the phone book and then when i exit the program and return back all the numbers are gone. SO is there any way to save the names and numbers entered into the program? Please give me the code as i am doing this for my class and they would be mad if the numbers disappeared everytime they exited the phonebook! PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Google `python persistence`...

Comment: Ask yourself: How do regular applications save data you've entered?

Comment: As Felix says, you need to "Google it up" and code it yourself, there is just no way to make a generic "save and load anything" without having any kind of detail how you need it to work.

Comment: At least you can just save the dictionary in a file every time before exiting, and load all the data from it at startup. Use a file format that is easy for you to read and write.

Comment: The OP is in the process of learning. Why not just suggest some choices instead of RTFM? Not sure about SO, but I think comp.lang.python always tried to be friendly and answer briefly and re-ask the question on the tutor mailing list http://www.python.org/community/lists/

Comment: show an example-code and we might show how to save your data.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not yet want to learn relational databases, NoSQL or cloud solutions, you can start by using [shelve module](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html).

Comment: mmmm can you guys specify a little more still in doubt if possible provide an easier tutorial or provide with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main problem is that you do store new values in your database, which is in this case represented with [dict](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), but your don't save it's condition between scripts executions. The time of existing of an object in your script - while the the script is running by interpreter and an object has some links to it. When your restart your program - you're starting to run your script all over again, and it stores in the dict only the elements, which were specified during the script.

The most simple solution, in my opinion, is to use python [pickle module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#). You're gonna save that dict in a file and then load it in the begging of your scrip and save it at the end.

you need to update script code with something like this:

```
default = {'Sarah': 7736815441,
             'John': 7736815442}
def start():
    #some code here, before you're trying to access phone numbers in your dict
    try:
        phonebook = pickle.load(open("data.pb", "r"))
    except IOError:
        phonebook = default

#your script here

def exit():
    #some code here, last chance to modify your dict,
    #so changes will appear in next program executions
    pickle.dump(phonebook, open("data.pb", "w"))
```

hope you're familiar with python functions, if no - you can read about then [here](http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/functions/)

Comment: Not only dicts, but also instances of user defined classes (with some limitations, which will not be probably an issue in your case) could be pickled.

Comment: Hello can you help me i am willing to give you the code can you modify it for me and send me? I really need this! Thanks

Comment: @RomanSusi yeah, I know that, but in this case, as I got it only dict is a changing object.

Comment: @VikaramVeerapandian well, we can try, but that's not te best way to learn. I do understand that it's easier to do it the way you want, but it's much much better for you to understand it on your own. And if you can't understand something specific - feel free to ask, that's what stackoverflow is all about.